# Command to download latest version of nvm?

Tags: bash, command-line, nvm

I am trying to install the latest version of `nvm` so ([per this article](https://davidwalsh.name/nvm)) I ran:

```
nvm install 4.0
```

It worked. But I want to make sure I install the latest version of nvm as they might have released a newer version after the article was written.

Is there a command I can run to download the latest version of nvm?

Comment: As of 2022 just do `nvm install --lts`

Answer (score 8):

These answers are all about updating the version of Node, when the original question is about updating the version of the NVM tool itself.

The script to update NVM is:

```
$ curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh | bash
```

and you can find the list of the latest releases here:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases

More details found here:
https://techsparx.com/nodejs/howto/nvm-deprecate-mirror.html

Answer (score 5):

You can run `nvm install node` to get the latest node release.

Comment: When I run `nvm install stable` I get the following error: `.nvm/node-vstable doesn't exist, (need to downloaded first?) stable`
`

Comment: According to the docs at https://github.com/creationix/nvm the ```stable``` alias is deprecated. Instead you'd want to use ```nvm install node```.

Comment: When I run `nvm install node`, I get the similar error again: `.nvm/node-vnode doesn't exist, (need to downloaded first?) node`

Comment: As per https://github.com/creationix/nvm/issues/809#issuecomment-132266089 make sure that you don't install ```nvm``` with ```npm``` and instead use the installation method specified in the https://github.com/creationix/nvm.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I have found so far involves a two-step process.

**Step 1**: List all the released versions.

```
nvm ls-remote
```

At the present time, the last item on this list is...

```
...
...
...
v6.1.0
```

**Step 2**: Download latest version on the list of available versions.

```
nvm install 6.1.0
```

Comment: As of 2022 just do `nvm install --lts`

Answer (score 0):

To automatically pick the most recent nvm tool version instead of having to look up the part like `v0.39.1` for the `wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash` command the following bash script can be used:

```
#!/bin/bash

nvm_string="nvm-sh/nvm";

git_latest_version() {
   basename $(curl -fs -o/dev/null -w %{redirect_url} https://github.com/$1/releases/latest)
}

latest_version_number=$(git_latest_version "${nvm_string}");
#echo ${latest_version_number}
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/${nvm_string}/${latest_version_number}/install.sh | bash
```

Usage (Linux, Mac):

Make a new file like `install-nvm.sh` e.g. with `vim` or `vi` or whatever. Then copy paste the above script (type `i` to insert, type `:wq` to save it), then do `sh install-nvm.sh`;

- [This solution was based on](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c)
- [Github nvm repo](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/releases/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install the latest/current version under the most recent major, then you don't need to pass any version number in your command.

- Case you want the **current version** (latest features) of node, you should use
  `nvm install node`
- Case you want the **latest lts version** (most stable) you should use
  `nvm install node --lts`

If you are looking for a **specific major or minor**, you should specify it:

- The following will get you the current version under the major 21
  `nvm install 21`
- The following will get you latest lts under the major 21
  `nvm install 21 --lts`